# Wordpress - Manual Approve Users + Assign Password

Tags: wordpress

I know that it's possible to manually approve new users that register into Wordpress site, but is it possible to hide the password field entirely in the registration form and assign these new users a password manually?

Comment: from where ? front end registration or backend? Also are you using default wordpress function or using any plugin?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like the user to register from front end only with name and email. He'll then receive an email saying his account will be reviewed and approved shortly.

I will then manually approve the account and manually create a password from the backend which I will then email to the user.

Currently I'm not using any plugin, just the default WP functionality ..